# Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined

Tags: jquery

К сайту подключен датапикер и русификатор названий в датапикере

```
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js"></script>
```

в консоли браузера выдается ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined 
bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js:6
(anonymous function) 
bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js:6
(anonymous function)
```

[image]

и русские названия не отображаются, все английскими
Jquery версии `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`,
изменений версии на 1.10.2 не помогло
в чем ошибка и как это исправить?

Comment: всё работает,  мб. у вас datepicker старый ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/E8Lvr/

там есть список использованных скриптов,

Comment: все работает в вёрстке, а когда подключаю к проекту - вот эта ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас файл локализцации попорчен, не fdatepicker, а datepicker, вот [посмотрите сюда](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js)

Comment: а что надо сделать, я что-то не понимаю? файл  и в верстке в таком виде отображается, но там все работает.

Comment: скачать bootstrap-datepicker.ru.js ещё раз.

Comment: да в общем оказалось достаточно убрать эту лишнюю букву f из файла и все заработало, не знаю, откуда она взялась, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

довольно удобные компоненты для bootstrap 3 http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/ и тот же datepicker сделан намного удобнее